# Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript</title>
        <link id="mycss" rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
        <script>

            function resize(s) {
                var styleSheet = document.getElementById('mycss').href;
                if (styleSheet.style.fontSize == '2.0em') { 
                        styleSheet.style.fontSize = parseFloat(styleSheet.style.fontSize) + (s * 0.2) + "em";
                    }else if(styleSheet.style.fontSize == '3.0em'){
                        styleSheet.style.fontSize = parseFloat(styleSheet.style.fontSize) + (s * 0.3) + "em";
                    }


            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="theBody" class="theBod">
        <h1 id = "h1" onclick="clickChange();">Hello</h1>
        <p id="para1" class="para1" onclick="resize(1);">Here is some text of one size (click)<p>
        <p id="para2" class="para2" onclick="resize(2)">More text of another size (click)<p>
        <p id ="demo" onclick="countToNum()"> Numbers (Click me): </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get it so that when an element is clicked the elements content grows in size by the specified parameter in the onclick function. I'm using an external style sheet

```
#para1 {
    font-size: 2.0em;
}

#para2{
    font-size: 3.0em;
}
```

this is all that is in the external style sheet. I just want the javascript to respond and only make the element that is clicked larger and the other element to remain the same. I keep receiving an error: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined

I'm really poor at javascript so help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.href`? Why? What? Huh? Uh...

Comment: Are you trying to change the size of font of text once it is clicked ?

Answer (score 2):

The main point:

> I just want the javascript to respond and only make the element that is clicked larger

For that, you don't want to access the stylesheet at all; instead, just access the style information of the clicked element:

```
<p onclick="resize(this)">...</p>
```

Then

```
function resize(element) {
    var elementStyle = element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element);
    // Read elementStyle.fontSize here, set element.style.fontSize to change it
}
```

---

Re the code in your question: This line:

> `var styleSheet = document.getElementById('mycss').href;`

gives you a string containing the URL of the stylesheet. It doesn't give you the stylesheet. Strings don't have a `style` property, so `styleSheet.style` is `undefined`, and `styleSheet.style.fontSize` fails because you tried to read a property from `undefined`.

If you want to access the stylesheet information, you'll want to find the style sheet in the [`document.styleSheets` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets).

**Or**, according to the HTML5 specification, [`HTMLLinkElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#htmllinkelement) implements the [`LinkStyle` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-LinkStyle) defined by CSSOM, which suggests that on conformant browsers you could use this to get the stylesheet:

```
var styleSheet = document.getElementById('mycss').sheet;
```

I haven't personally done that, just followed the information in the specs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to access the stylesheet, just reset the font size dynamically:

```
function resize(element, resizeFactor) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(element);
    var currentSize = parseInt(elem.style.fontSize, 10);
    var newSize = currentSize + resizeFactor;
    elem.style.fontSize = newSize + "px";
}
```

Your current code is (I assume) trying to get the current size out of the external CSS stylesheet, but you aren't accessing the stylesheet correctly: `document.getElementById('mycss').href` returns the URL string of the stylesheet not the stylesheet itself. For that you should be using `document.styleSheets` - see [here](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) for a good tutorial.

Essentially you can get the stylesheet object using `document.styleSheets[index]` then add CSS rules to it using `this.addRule()`.